# Web scraping "cwjobs" website using python not working

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()


# Navigate to the website
url = "https://www.cwjobs.co.uk/jobs/cloud-security-engineer?searchOrigin=Resultlist_top-search"
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the job listings to load
job_listings = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".jobsearch-SerpJobCard")))


# Create a CSV file and write the header
with open('job_listings.csv', mode='w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['Title', 'Company', 'Location', 'Salary', 'Summary'])

    # Loop through the job listings and write the data to the CSV file
    for job in job_listings:
        title = job.find_element_by_css_selector('.title a').text
        company = job.find_element_by_css_selector('.company').text
        location = job.find_element_by_css_selector('.location').text
        salary = job.find_element_by_css_selector('.salaryText').text if job.find_element_by_css_selector('.salaryText') else ''
        summary = job.find_element_by_css_selector('.summary').text
        writer.writerow([title, company, location, salary, summary])

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Getting this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\OneDrive\Documents\Python\test.py", line 16, in 
job_listings = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".jobsearch-SerpJobCard")))
File "C:\Users\salma\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

this is the file it creates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yheq.png)

Comment: The CSS Selector `.jobsearch-SerpJobCard` is not available as of today.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to expand the timeout from 10 to 20 seconds by editing line 16 WebDriverWait(driver, 20). If that’s not enough I suggest to expand the timeout to a working value.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but didnt work. I first tried it with the indeed.com site. Did the same thing